# GWT Developer Plugin is not running

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, gwt

I run a Web Application as sample project using Eclipse then I opened the URL provided by the IDE (`http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`) and my Chrome browser (version: 42) showed me a message: "Development Mode requires the GWT Developer Plug-in".

I downloaded the plug-in and it was installed on my browser (I checked it at chrome://extensions/) then I restarted the browser and entered the same link again but it still shows me the same message.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GWT plugin is no longer supported by Chrome due to NPAPI being deprecated (https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation).

To debug your application, you'll need to do one of the following:

1. Temporarily enable NPAPI in Chrome

   chrome://flags/#enable-npapi
2. Downgrade Chrome to a version that supports the plugin
3. Update your application to use SuperDevMode - http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html